# How to Encode ArrayList to utf-8

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

The problem is that I am sending `JSON`. In the DB  instead of Cyrillic, question mark.

I doing:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arraylist.add("first");
    arraylist.add("second");
    arraylist.add("third");
    arraylist.add("fourth");
```

Then I convert `ArrayList` to `Json`

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(arrayList);
```

Sending:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Application.TEST_API);
List<NameValuePair> valuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", "SAVE_RESULT"));
valuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("result", jsonString));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valuePairs));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Question:

1) How to Convert to `jsonString` my array in `UTF-8`?

2) Or a problem when sending, `where httppost.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity (valuePairs))`, since, `UrlEncodedFormEntity ()`

```
public UrlEncodedFormEntity(List<? extends NameValuePair> parameters) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this(parameters, "ISO-8859-1");
}
```

Comment: As long you stay within java, the characterset is nothing about to worry about. But where the string leaves java (i.e. is serialized) the used characterset matters. This happens somewhere in the used HttpClient or HttPost implementations. Look in the documentations of these classes how to set the character set.

Comment: Heri, That is, the problem is not in android can be on the server?

Comment: You have to watch the outcome of your serialization process (what byte array is really sent to the server?). Then you can decide of the problem is on the client or on the server side. On the server side it is the same problem: The received byte stream has to be converted into strings using the same character set. When it comes to save it into the DB you have to obey the string conversions needed by the DB.